# How to make logger log PID on CentOS7

Tags: centos, centos7, syslog, pid

i found [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) for logger stating one can use --id=$$ to log the pid of the calling script. unfortunatly this is not working with logger in centos7.

what is the proper way of logging pid to syslog in centos7?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context, such as where/how you are calling logger? What are you seeing in the resulting logs? Is there no PID, or the 'wrong' PID?

Comment: sorry - should have included that in my initial post - i call "logger --id=$$ some msg" and i get "logger: option '--id' doesn't allow an argument"

Answer (score 0):

Your issues seems to be down a slight difference in what the man page you link to says is supported, and what your logger actually supports.

I just checked a centOS7 system, and I can replicate your issue:

```
$ sudo logger --help

Usage:
 logger [options] [message]

Options:
 -T, --tcp             use TCP only
 -d, --udp             use UDP only
 -i, --id              log the process ID too
 <snip>

$ sudo logger --id=11 test
logger: option '--id' doesn't allow an argument
```

So on centOS7, logger will only allow you to include (or not) the PPID, it does not allow you to set the PID to something arbitrary.

So `logger --id some msg` will **NOT** work, and is **NOT** equivalent to what `logger --id=$$ some msg` would have done.

I should have checked the output more thoroughly before suggesting it was, thanks @[user3347114](https://serverfault.com/users/355002/user3347114) for correcting me.

Comment: unfortunatly "logger --id some msg"  is not equivalent to "logger --id=$$ some msg" - the pid logger writes is  not the same as the pid of the calling process - therefore every invocation of logger within the same script logs with a different PID. that makes the whole idea of logging the PID pretty useless....